# Sci fi movie with a blind skeletal robot hunting a man in a warehouse

Tags: story-identification, movie

I only saw one scene when I was a kid.

It was about a machine that looked like the skeleton terminator in a warehouse setting I think, and it was passing by a terrified man who didn't make any noise because the machine couldn't identify him with its eyes. It did stop and turn its head and stared straight into the man's face, but then moved on.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year would this have been?  How sure are you it was a movie and not a TV show?  Was it live-action?

Comment: Probably not it, but I'm reminded of the Life Hutch episode of Love, Death & Robots.

Comment: Maybe that scene in Westworld? Yul Brynner with his face melted off, trying to see Richard Benjamin with badly damaged heat vision?

Comment: Possibly Death Machine, from 1994? The robot's hardware is all exposed, which gives it a skeletal look, but is more beast-like than humanoid, although it walks on two legs. The robot hunts by sensing fear, instead of visually.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're describing the final chase scene in the film *[Westworld](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070909/)* (1973). Yul Brynner's character 'The Gunslinger' is designed for outdoor use and mistakes our character's heat pattern for that of a torch.

He gets blinded with acid and fire and ends up basically just a walking robotic frame hunting down our hapless protagonist.